# Substituting with an uppercase version from a set of capture groups

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to do the following

Find any of these words: SELECT / FROM / WHERE
They can be in any case e.g. Select / froM / wHere

Then replace each word with its uppercase equivalent.

I'm trying to do this using `SSMS` find and replace, which uses `.NET` regex.

The default find setting is case-insensitive. The following finds the words ok:

```
(SELECT)|(FROM)|(WHERE)
```

But if I do the following in the replace the words just stay in whatever case they are originally written in:

```
$1$2$3
```

Is there a way to do this in one step?

Comment: If there is no `\U`/`\E` opertor support, then it is not possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks Wiktor - that is a shame. I guess your comment is actually the answer to my question if you wish to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future viewers I've added this answer.

As Wiktor Stribizew commented if there is no support for the `\U` operator support then it is not possible.

I'm opening the files in a different editor `Notepad++` and doing the following:

Search expression:
`(select|sum|into|where | on |from |join |inner |outer | as | cast|union )`
Replace expression:
`\U$1`